# OpenMPI code runs on command line but not through python subprocess or shell script

Tags: shell, python-2.7, subprocess, mpi, openmpi

I am trying to run MPI on a virutal cluster using KVM. 
My OpenMPI code runs fine when run through terminal using:

```
mpiuser@niru:~$ mpirun -n 5 -hostfile /home/mpiuser/hosts /home/mpiuser/hello
```

However, when I run my python script,using

```
$sudo python test.py
```

test.py:

```
import subprocess
p=subprocess.Popen(['mpirun -n 5 -hostfile /home/mpiuser/hosts /home/mpiuser/hello'],shell=True)
```

I get the  error :

```
 ssh: connect to host test0 port 22: No route to host
ssh: connect to host test1 port 22: No route to host
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
A daemon (pid 6608) died unexpectedly with status 255 while attempting
to launch so we are aborting.

There may be more information reported by the environment (see above).

This may be because the daemon was unable to find all the needed shared
libraries on the remote node. You may set your LD_LIBRARY_PATH to have the
location of the shared libraries on the remote nodes and this will
automatically be forwarded to the remote nodes.
```

So I tried running the command using shell script, but I get the same error.

```
sudo sh ./launch.sh
```

launch.sh:

```
 mpirun -n 5 -hostfile /home/mpiuser/hosts /home/mpiuser/hello
```

I also tried exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH on my computer :

```
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi
```

Why does mpirun work in command line and not through Python or Shell Script? Please help!

---

update: the contents of my ~/.ssh/config file are:

```
Host test0 
Hostname 192.168.122.98
User mpiuser
PubKeyAuthentication yes
IdentityFile /home/mpiuser/cloudKey

Host test1
Hostname 192.168.122.195
User mpiuser
PubKeyAuthentication yes
IdentityFile /home/mpiuser/cloudKey
```

Comment: It says `No route to host`, i.e. `mpirun` cannot establish SSH connections to both `test0` and `test1` for some reason. Check the network configuration. Also, why are you running the Python/shell script as root?

Comment: Do you have any host-specific configurations in your `~/.ssh/config` file? It is possible that `test0` and `test1` are not real hostnames but only SSH aliases configured in `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: @HristoIliev: yes, `test0` and `test1` are aliases in `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: Running the commands with `sudo` fails most likely since the aliases are not configured in `/root/.ssh/config`.

Comment: Thanks! it worked perfectly after configuring `/root/.ssh/config`. :)
I was running my script with sudo as I had to edit some VM config files